# What is so special about the U47 mic?

Tags: recording, microphone

I constantly hear awesome testimonials about the U47 and I was wondering why it is considered such a good mic. or is it?
What are some typical uses for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of it is the wide area of a relatively constant proximity effect, so the speaker/ singer can move quite freely without a drastic change in sound.

Answer (score 0):

What makes it special nowadays is the classic, well known sound for singers. People expect singers to sound like U47 U87 ...